Probability of constituent distributions
I have a set of N normal distributions representing the points a person can get in a competition. The mean and std deviation of each of these distributions is known, and for simplicity's sake, let's imagine they have no skew. Let us also imagine that these distributions are independent.
In such a system, the person with the highest points wins the competition.
From the additive properties of normal distribution, we know that adding these constituent normal distribution together yield another normal distribution.
My question is: Is there a way to extract the probability of a person winning the competition?
I have tried taking the assumption that the probability of a person winning the competition is equal to the product of all the difference probabilities (i.e. CDF of a difference normal distributions at 0) between the person under question and all other persons. I seem to have gotten a decent result for the best performing person, but the others were too low.
Thank you!
PS: A MonteCarlo test has already been performed to verify claims about independence, the total normal distributions, and the performance of the attempt made.


You start by presuming normal distributions and then add "for simplicity's sake, let's imagine they have no skew". All normal distributions are already  symmetric, so this adds no information.



If the winner is the one with rhe largest sum, the components don't seem to be needed. Just specify the mean and variance of the total using basic properties of means and variances. ... 3. What is not clear is whether the distributions are different for each competitor. Please clarify. ... 4. Either way, it looks like this is a duplicate


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Because the negative of a Normal variable also has a Normal distribution, the question about which variable achieves the minimum is equivalent to this one.

Thanks @whuber and Glen_b for taking the time. Indeed, this can be reduced into the duplicate answer you have posted here. You put me in the right direction!
